# Adding cookies while redirecting in play framework

Tags: playframework, httpcookie

I want send a redirect(String) response from my controller to redirect customer to a partner web page.

Before redirecting, I want to add some cookies. I tried like following:

```
response().setCookie(cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue());
return redirect(redirectUrl);
```

However, when redirection happens, cookies are not set and hence not sent to partner web page.

How can I add cookies before redirection?

Regards,
Suraj

Comment: is partner page and your pages in a same domain?

Comment: I have no Idea what are cookie.getName() and cookie.getValue() in your post. It seems you are getting values instead of setting values. I wrote syntax of setting cookie in separate answer.

Comment: Partner domain is different than our domain.

Comment: cookie.getName() and cookie.getValue() : cookie is a object of type "org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie". We get the cookie values from our partner which we have to send them back during redirection for validating the session.

Comment: Ok. So you need two cookies when domains are different. Please check the long answer below.

Answer (score 1):

A cookie can not be shared between two domains (except sub-domains). You need two cookies on both domains with similar name and value. This is possible by redirecting visitors to partner website while you send cookie name and cookie value as query to a special page of partner website. They set the cookie on their domains and redirect back the visitor to your website again.

For security reasons it is recommended to encrypt query data to prevent visitors to simulate other cookies by fake names and values.